# Something more than multi-label classification?

Tags: machine-learning

My training data has millions of rows with diagnosis and medicines prescribed for them by multiple doctors.

An example row:-

```
Doctor name:  John ;
Diagnosis:  diabetes, hypertension;
Medications:  ABC, XYZ, KLP, FG-2 ;
```

Note: We are not aware which medicine is used to treat which diagnosis.

I need to be able to predict the medicines the doctor will prescribe given the diagnosis and doctor name.

Which machine learning modelling can be used here? I feel it's a bit more complex that multi-label classification.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple algorithms you can try (nearest neighbors, approximating probability distribution and using it for ML estimator), but in this case, it looks that the best way is to look the most frequent medication that a doctor uses for a given diagnosis and take that medication.

It's true there are the cases in which the doctor has not seen the disease yet but it's solvable (through other doctors maybe).

A better method can be used if you assume more about the model, but it's great for starters.